# Geo-Reference PointCloud2

Tags: ros, 3dmapping, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi There!

Could someone please provide me some reading/method for the best practice of producing a geo-referenced point cloud.
I have an SBG systems AHRS (RTK GPS and IMU fused at 200hz) and a LiDAR. Both of which have ROS drivers already.
How can I produce the point cloud in the world frame rather than the robot?
What is the minimum requirement for publishers/subscribers/nodes since the SBG publishes:

```
    ros::Publisher imu_raw_pub;

    ros::Publisher imu_head_pub; //todo magnitometer data

    ros::Publisher gps_pos_pub;

    ros::Publisher gps_vel_pub;

    ros::Publisher gps_head_pub;

    ros::Publisher ekf_pose_pub;

    ros::Publisher ekf_quat_pub;

    ros::Publisher time_pub;
```

Appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267707/geo-reference-pointcloud2/) by [sammas](https://answers.ros.org/users/31386/sammas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-07-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The recommended way to geo reference data is using the common transforms outlined in [REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0